# Problems with the function "sf_readf_float" of library "sndfile.h"

Tags: c++, wav, libsndfile

I have a project about speech recognition. Although I used library "sndfile.h", I am stuck in reading input sound. I have a question: the data which was read by function `sf_readf_float()` is time-domain signal, isn't it? If not, then what is it? Is there any formula to transform it to time-domain signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the data that libsndfile returns is time-domain data: the audio samples from the input file. The function [`sf_readf_float`](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#readf) returns the samples in "frames", one frame being a set of samples from each channel at a given point in time. Also, `sf_readf_float` scales the samples to be in the range [-1.0, 1.0] - see [`this note`](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#note1) for details.

Have a look at [sndfile-tools](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/tools) for example code that reads sound files using libsndfile. The [sndfile-mix-to-mono](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/tools/#mix-to-mono) example should be a good starting point.